# Back button not working for my manually loaded UIWebView for external website

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

**Technologies**: Swift, iOS8.1.3, XCode 6, Maverick

I've added a "rewind" back button to my UIWebview via the main.storyboard and connected it here on my view with a backButton func:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate  {
  @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView! 
  var detailItem: NSURL?
  var grabData = false

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false;
 }

 @IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.webView.goBack()
  }

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let url = self.detailItem {
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request:  
    NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if grabData {
        grabData = false
        return true
    } else {
        grabData = true
        manuallyLoadPage(request)
        return false
    }
}

func manuallyLoadPage(request: NSURLRequest) {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (data, response, error) invar html = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
        html = html.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</head>", withString: "<styles><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='link-to-styles.css' media='all'></styles></head>", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: response.URL!)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

My back button doesn't do anything when clicked and I want it to show the previous webpage. I think it has something to do with how I am intercepting the session and manually loading the WebView. Maybe it doesn't know what the original base url is? Something else?

Comment: have you checked with breakpoint whether your function backButton is called?

Comment: @rishi yeah looks like when I click on the button, the function gets called..

Comment: @rishi  I think it has something to do with how I am intercepting the session and manually loading the WebView.

Comment: There is way to check whether your web view can go back or not, use method "canGoBack" and check this.

Comment: Hey @rishi yeah looks like it returns false when hitting the if webView.canGoBack statement. Any thoughts on how to fix this?